# How can I block or auto-delete incoming blank/empty SMS/MMS messages?

Tags: mms, sms-blocking

I am looking for an app (or any method really) that will catch incoming text messages that are blank and automatically delete or block them.  Blocking the number/contact it comes from is not an option in this case.

This is for a Droid Turbo 2, Android 7.0, not rooted.
The messaging app receiving the messages is Textra.

Comment: SMS is system level stuff even if you are using a third party app. Without root , I am afraid it's not possible . Even with root , I don't know how maybe with Tasker